# Alternatives for "conducted" with respect to research

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

Literature review is a big part of my life. I usually use “[Scientist] *conducted* a research using data from” to state a previous study.

Do you have recommendations of other verbs to use? I am tired of keeping using *conduct* (and I am not sure whether it is correct) and really want to diversify.

Comment: "Conducted a research" sounds incorrect. Usually, we'd see "conducted a research study" or something.

Comment: @Kit: I just edited that very thing. OP no doubt made a typo, since the question is "The verb before 'research'," not "The verb before 'a research'."

Comment: I doubt it was a typo. It's a common ESL marker. I think it should stand unedited in the question, especially since there is already one answer which refers to it.

Comment: @MετάEd: I edited before the question was answered.

Comment: @Robusto I can readily believe your edit and tchrist's answer "crossed in the mail". Happens all the time. Nevertheless.

Comment: @MετάEd: You make an assumption that this is an ESL question, which implies a non-native speaker. Do you have evidence for that?

Comment: @Robusto You have no doubt it is a typo. Where is your evidence for *that*? I went by the user's profile.

Comment: I am new here and I am totally confused by the conversation (and the editing). To clarify, (1) yes, question proposed by non-native speaker; (2) no typo, coz I knew that "research" is "an" uncountable noun.

Comment: "Conducted a research" is only incorrect because "research" isn't countable. This is fixed by dropping the article: "conducted research".

Comment: Oh. I just re-corrected it *again* before reading all this. B ut what's the point of leaving an irrelevant error in the text?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just that tchrist did a good job of not only addressing the specific question but also addressing the surrounding grammar. If you go back and change the grammar in the question, his answer becomes somewhat disjoint.

Comment: @Stefanie: If the later "research" simply uses "data from...a previous study", perhaps it would sometimes be appropriate to say *"[Scientist] [re-]analysed data from..."* I assume your problem is you keep getting caught up in repetitions of the general form *"[Scientist B] conducted research using data from a previous study conducted by [Scientist A]"*

Comment: _*A research_ **is** incorrect. I've only encountered it in Indian and Chinese Englishes, where it appears to be entrenched in academic circles. In the US _research_ is never a singular count noun; _researches_ occurs, meaning different types of, or an awful lot of, _research_. But individual projects are _a research project/paper/thesis/dissertation/lab,_ etc. And one uses whatever verb is appropriate for those words; none is appropriate for _*a research_

Answer (score 17):

You actually can’t conduct **a** research, because it is not a count noun.

But you can *conduct, do, pursue, guide, lead, head, preside over*, or *engage in* research.

Other more courageous terms include *chaperon, shepherd,* and *trailblaze*.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: _Carry out_ seems to have been missed.

Comment: *Courageous?* Fools rush in where angels (and even [Humpty Dumpty](http://wordspy.com/words/HumptyDumptylanguage.asp)) fear to tread!

Answer (score 11):

Can you use:

> **Scientists. . .**
>
> ***"studied"***
>
> ***"researched"***
>
> ***"evaluated"***
>
> ***"analyzed"***

Answer (score 7):

Besides the suggestions offered already, you could look up [synonyms of *conduct* in a thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/conduct). This should give you candidates such as *directed*, *performed*, *oversaw*, etc.

Another alternative is to query a collocations database [such as this one](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). Querying it with the string `[v?d*] research` threw up words such as *established*, *compiled*, and *pursued*.

Comment: I'm sure *pioneered* does indeed often turn up before *research*, but it wouldn't suit OP's context at all, which specifically mentions a relationship to *a previous study*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. I hadn't noticed that.